# Semantic ui don't want border box in input feild

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

in reactjs i get a input box but my problem is i don't want any border and i tried to add css to fix it but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what i m doing wrong. i even tried to add div transparent class.

Code :

```
<div class="ui transparent input">
<Form.Input style={{ border: "0cm", borderRadius: "0cm", marginBottom: "20px", marginLeft: 
"0.4cm", background: "white", borderBottom: "2px solid #006400", width: "59.7cm",  outline: 
"none" }}
                    error={errors.kookId ? { content: errors.kookId } : null}
                    name="kookId"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={kookId}
                    autoFocus />
         </div>
```

Comment: can you add a small codesandbox ?

Comment: any progress ???

Comment: no, i m afraid. Nithing works